# Need to write DSL to check if these 4 events occur within 1 second in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

```
1. 31628 2021-02-13T00:20:49.325893Z - xyz all/repos open
2. 31628 2021-02-13T00:20:49.607437Z - xyz all/repos get-latest
3. 31628 2021-02-13T00:20:49.888794Z - xyz all/repos reparent 
4. 31628 2021-02-13T00:20:50.170101Z - xyz all/repos stat
```

I need to write DSL query such that, it should show up document groups like these (i.e., group of 4 documents with open, get-latest, reparent, stat). All 4 must be within one second range as shown in above logs.

Please help me.

Comment: please add sample document and expected result

Comment: @jaspreetchahal sample document consists of logs similar to above & expected result is to find group of documents like these.